# Unable to access knife in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am very new to chef, trying to learn it. I have installed chef-client on my system, copied the .pem files and knife.rb file in the chef directory of my chef-repo and now I am trying to access knife but I am getting following error. Can anyone help me out ?

```
prateek@prateek-desktop:~/mygit/chef-repo/chef$ knife client list -VV
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/mixin/path_sanity.rb:26:in `enforce_path_sanity': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/knife.rb:465:in `run_with_pretty_exceptions'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/knife.rb:173:in `run'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:123:in `run'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.0/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/knife:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/knife:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Looking at the source its failing at the line `existing_paths = env["PATH"].split(path_separator)`, which suggests you don't have a PATH environment variable defined.

Comment: @JaredRussell You should make that comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, I need to configure my PATH environment variable :)